# Reading csv file with paragraphs and escape characters in text

Tags: r, csv, escaping, read.csv

I have a csv file containing ~1,500 rows which I want to read into R. The file contains text which in turn contains new paragraphs (`<p>`). `read.csv()` seems to interpret them as different lines, so I end up with > 5,000 rows in my data frame. My question is: how do I get R to ignore the `<p>` signs and ideally all special characters which I have not spotted yet?

Background: the text is retrieved from the source code of a website, which is why many programming characters occur.

Here is a sample line:

```
text_col = c("["<p>Welcome to Y. The xyz.</p>" "<p>We are a small team based in Z with a diverse experience set that enables us to think out of the box.</p>"])
```

My attempt was to use `read.delim()`, however it does not seem to work:

```
read.delim(file = "ABC.csv", delim = "<p>",escape_double=FALSE, escape_backslash=TRUE, quote="'")
```

Comment: Is the delimiter a comma or the paragraph symbol? Also, what is your desired output for your sample line?

Comment: the delimiter is a comma and the line is supposed to be read as a single row and field of a dataframe with dim(1,1) instead 3-4 as currently

Comment: I am able to get it working with `read.table()` assuming the line is one long character string (wrapped in `'`). Is that the case? If so, I will post an answer

Comment: That does not work for me using read.table(file = "abc.csv", sep = ";", colClasses=c("V2"="character")) and wrapping each line in " ' "